# FullCalendar функция для weekNumberCalculation

Tags: jquery, yii

Делаю расписание занятий. Нужно чтобы в календаре номера недель отображались не с начала года, а с начала сентября. В [документации](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/weekNumberCalculation/) сказано

> You may also specify a function, which must accept a single Moment and return an integer week number.

Пишу функцию `function() { var week = moment().week()-35; return week; }` не работает, недели отображаются с начала года, просто `moment().week()-35;` та же самая история.

Есть ли какой-либо рабочий пример функции для weekNumberCalculation?
Использую расширение FullCalendar для Yii, но суть от этого не меняется.

UPD. с функцией разобрался, номера недель поменялись, но теперь они все одинаковы)

UPD2. Разобрался. В функцию передаётся выбранная дата. Код такой:

```
'weekNumberCalculation'=>new CJavaScriptExpression("function getWeekNumber(d) {
                    d = new Date(+d);
                    // Начало семестра
                    var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(),8,1);
                    var weekNo = Math.ceil(1+(( (d - yearStart) /86400000))/7);
                    if (weekNo < 0) { return 0 }
                    else {return weekNo};
                                                        }"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу ошибаться, однако в самой документации написано (ссылка та же, что и у вас в вопросе) , что при создании момента можно "явно" указать дату т.е.

```
moment('2016-09-01');
```

Поэтому нужно проставить верную дату внутри момента и убрать -35 (не совсем понял зачем это нужно).

Update 
Вот кусок исходного кода fullCalendar. Как я понял, можно просто для ваших целей вернуть нужное число в функции. 

`// assign a normalized value, to be used by our .week() moment extension
    localeData._fullCalendar_weekCalc = (function(weekCalc) {
        if (typeof weekCalc === 'function') {
            return weekCalc;
        }
        else if (weekCalc === 'local') {
            return weekCalc;
        }
        else if (weekCalc === 'iso' || weekCalc === 'ISO') {
            return 'ISO';
        }
})(options.weekNumberCalculation);`

Я бы попытался вот так 

`... .weekNumberCalculation(function(){
    var local = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01T12:00:00');
    return local.week()-35; // нужно смотреть значение week тут
});`

Я пытался сделать это в jsfiddle но он мне сказал что есть ошибка в подключаемой либе... поэтому за правильность не ручаюсь.

Comment: -35 нужно для вычисления нужной учебной недели, например 38 неделя в году это 3 неделя в году учебном

Comment: К сожалению, Вашим способом тоже не вышло

Comment: т.е. вот такое объявление момента `var local = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01T12:00:00');` не возвращает нужную неделю ? странно

Comment: Может быть потому что я использую расширение FullCalendar для Yii? Не могли бы Вы указать полностью, что нужно написать в `weekNumberCalculation:`

Comment: Обновил ответ - мб поможет

Comment: Скрипт запустился, но теперь все недели в календаре одинаковые `'weekNumberCalculation'=>new CJavaScriptExpression("function(){var local = moment(); return local.week()-35;}")`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ckvngu

Comment: Ну так ты сам так написал) Оно все верно пишет т.к. тебе нужно написать теперь функцию, которая будет возвращать номера недель во времени. Т.е. момент задается один, а применяешь ты его ко всему календарю. Нужно moment() сделать "глобальным" (ну почти - по крайней мере, чтобы он был доступен внутри фнукции и мог быть использован в иттерациях). А потом просто при каждом доступе к функции внутри делать +1 к значению, пока не достигнет ограничения недель (школьный год завершается в мае-июне ведь).

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, в функцию нужно было передавать аргумент, в виде текущей даты)

Answer (score 0):

```
'weekNumberCalculation'=>new CJavaScriptExpression("function getWeekNumber(d) {
                d = new Date(+d);
                // Начало семестра
                var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(),8,1);
                var weekNo = Math.ceil(1+(( (d - yearStart) /86400000))/7);
                if (weekNo < 0) { return 0 }
                else {return weekNo};
                                                    }"),
```